# Android завершает приложение

Tags: android

Подскажите, написал простенькое приложение под андроид, которое периодически опрашивает свой сервак по сети. Заметил, что со временем андроид завершает его, как предположение при не хватке памяти или при малом заряде батареи. Но другие приложения продолжают работать, например OpenVPN. Подскажите в какую сторону копать, как сделать так, чтобы приложение не завершалось, имело высокий приоритет или что-то в этом духе!

Answer (score 4):

Когда у телефона не хватает оперативной памяти, он начинает уничтожать процессы по приоритетам.

Если грубо говорить, то сначала уничтожаются активити, затем сервисы, затем сервисы с пометкой foreground. (Да не отрежут мне пальцы за такое пояснение коллеги).

Что-бы этого не случалось, вам нужно часть логики перенести в Service, в таком случае система с меньшим шансом возьмет именно ваше приложение для освобождения памяти.

UPD: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, как раз читаю про службы, но уверенности что это поможет не было. Получается никак от завершения не защититься? Если не сложно, в двух словах расскажите как например работает будильник на телефоне, он же вроде ни при каких условиях не завершается.

Comment: @ДноДонное обновил ответ.
Будильник на телефоне - для начала стандартное приложение, идущее к любому телефону, не могу говорить точно - только ли работа на сервисе позволяет никогда не выключаться этому приложению. Однако там просто есть сервис, который содержит в себе intent с Alarm Manager'ом, с датой и временем. Когда нужная дата и время наступают - то intent запускается.

Answer (score 4):

Видимые процессы одни из самых высоких по приоритету в Android, и они выше системных. Задача ваш Service сделать видимым, а если точней вывести на передний план. Использовав метод [startForeground](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification))

```
void startForeground (int id, Notification notification)
```

Именно то уведомление, которым злоупотребляют некоторые известные апки, которое можно остановить только в процессах лаунчера.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Дополню ответы коллег, если у Вас Android 6.0, то все становится еще сложнее.

В данном обновлении появились так называемые режимы Doze mode и App Standby.

Doze Mode — режим «отключки», в который переходят все устройства на Marshmallow после некоторого времени обездвижения без зарядки. 
App Standby — автоматическое лишение приложений доступа к ресурсам устройства, всех которые давно не открывал пользователь.

Вот здесь можно почитать поподробнее [хабр](https://habrahabr.ru/post/269491/)

Вот здесь можно послушать про нововведения 6.0, про вышеперечисленные режимы мотайте ближе к концу [AndroidDev](http://apptractor.ru/AndroidDev/podcast1.html)