# Как сделать, чтоб service не выключался при закрытии приложения?

Tags: java, android, service

Когда запускаем service, то можно выйти из приложения, но оно продолжит выполнение.  Но если удалить приложение из вкладок,  то оно закроется,  а не просто свернется...

Но есть же ведь,допустим, бродкаст ресивер,  который можно поставить на прослушивание запуска девайса,  и как только девайс запущен,  то начинается выполнение чего либо...  Ведь при этом, приложение и не открывается и во вкладках его нет...

Значит, наверное, как-то можно запустить сервис так, чтоб он точно отработал?

У меня ситуация с передачей данных на сервер,  в зависимости от качества интернета это может занять какое-то время...  Я вот думаю, пока в сервисе будет бежать передача данных, юзер удалит приложение из вкладок и процесс прирвется...

Comment: Попробуйте запустить из сервиса уведомление, в коем можно показать процесс загрузки `startForeground()` (вроде так пишется). В таком виде, вроде, не будет сервис прибит при смахивании приложения юзером.

Comment: У вас ошибочное понимание BroadcastReceiver, он не висит в процессах, он зареген в системе и срабатывает каждый раз как произойдет определенный процесс, что-то вроде CallBack, только на уровне device. Его метод onRecive срабатывает и сразу же убивается, причем его жизнь очень коротка, в р-не 10 сек. после система его дропает вне зависимости от действий. 
у компонента Service совершенно другая жизнь - тоже бурная, но не настолько импульсивная)) Выше вот отличный коммент, вы же видели Notif когда идет обновление приложений, попробуйте смахнуть.

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei я понимаю как работает `BroadcastReceiver`, но мой вопрос был в том, как сделать так, чтоб процесс не убивался когда юзер смахивает приложение... Исходя из вашего ответа, я не до конца понял, девайс убьет сервис если смахнуть приложение или нет?

Comment: вы не сможете его смахнуть в этом то и дело http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/545233/191270